# Need a better way to valid Computer name using C++ code

Tags: winapi

I am not trying to set the local hostname. In my app using a edit control need to accept a host name (fully qualified with DNS / without).

We do know we cannot use chars a (\ / ! @ # $ % ^). Is there a better way than programmatically parsing the user input.

Code needs to work in all languages (multi byte char set)

Thanks
AnilG

Comment: How is restricting the hostname helping the user?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I could think of. The effort to do this yourself is pretty slim, though. See [_mbschr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34ccac3%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [_mbscspn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe8sk0x7%28VS.71%29.aspx) for good examples on how to search for a single character and multiple characters.

There is also a good overview over string functions supported by Visual Studio [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0151s4x%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
char string[] = "xyzabc";
int pos;

pos = strcspn( string, "abc" );
printf( "First a, b or c in %s is at character %d\n", string, pos );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library to match the string against a regular expression.